# Event that is triggered when a user selects any item from an autocomplete textbox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, autocomplete, textbox

Is there any event in VB.NET that is triggered when a user selects any item from an autocomplete `TextBox`?

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub txtFilterBy_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles txtFilterBy.TextChanged
    txtSearch("Select Name From items", txtFilterBy)
End Sub

Public Sub txtSearch(ByVal strsql As String, ByVal textboxName As TextBox)
    con.ConnectionString = constr
    Excercise_Add.con.Open()
    Dim namesCollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(strsql,con)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    read = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While (read.Read)
        namesCollection.Add(read(0).ToString())
    End While
    textboxName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    textboxName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection
    textboxName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean, *other* than `TextChanged`?

Comment: Yes. textchanged is i am using to populate the  custom autocomplete source.